# Is UserDetailsService "legacy" and what is the modern or idiomatic way to load a user?

Tags: spring-security

Spring Security's SAML2 documentation implies that UserDetailsService is "legacy": https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/saml2/login/authentication.html#servlet-saml2login-opensamlauthenticationprovider-userdetailsservice

"Or, perhaps you would like to include user details from a legacy UserDetailsService. In that case, the response authentication converter can come in handy..."

What is the more modern or idiomatic way to load a logged-in user's information?

Comment: I think you will find the answer of your question on answers of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630818/spring-security-custom-authentication-authenticationprovider-vs-userdetailsser) and also legacy != deprecated